# Issue with Jira filter query

Tags: mysql, jira, jira-filter

Our office uses `Jira` for project management and I have come to love the platform.

I have setup a bunch of filters for specific project and others, however I am coming across an issue with one of my filter queries.

One each ticket there are `assignees`, `reporters`, and `watchers`; on one of our project we have a field for `testers`.

I have two filters setup on my dashboard, one for tickets that I'm actively involve with as either a reporter, tester, or assignee; next to that I'm trying to create a filter that just shows the things that I'm watching, trying to eliminate overlap with the previous.

Here is the filter query that I have come up with:

> (watcher in (currentUser()) OR reporter in (currentUser())) AND assignee not in (currentUser()) AND Tester not in (currentUser()) AND status != Closed ORDER BY created

Now the issue that I'm having is that the field `Tester` is only specific to one project, and is the primary field that I need to filter by; all other projects do not have this field. The result is that I will only see results from the projects that have this field, and even though I am watching tickets in other projects, the filter does not display them.

Is there a way to adjust the query such that it will only check that field if it exists? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if tester is null to include all of the other results. So

and ( tester not in current user or tester = null)

Not real code (on a tablet) but the autoo complete should help get it right